# On an important equality in probability with integral

Tags: probability

My question is probably a bit simple but I don't reach to understand.

Indeed, if I have a probability space $(\Omega, F , \mathbb{P})$ and $X$ a random variable with density $p$, how do I have the equality :
$$
\int x d\mathbb{P}_X = \int x p(x) dx
$$

I know that $\mathbb{P}_X(B)= \int_B p dx$, but I don't reach to understand why the equality is true.

Thanks a lot for your consideration,

Comment: Do you know about Radon-Nikodym derivatives? If not, then here's an heuristic justification. $p(x)$ should be thought off as $\frac{d P}{d\lambda}$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}$. So $\int x dP=\int x \frac{dP}{d\lambda(x)}d\lambda(x)=\int xp(x)\,d\lambda(x)$

Comment: This result is a special case of the law of the unconscious statistician (for the identity map).

Comment: Show it for indicator functions, then it holds by linearity. Then it holds my monotone convergence for non negative random variables and thus for all integrable random variables